# Submit autocomplete with enter button without refreshing the page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get the query results by hitting the enter button on the drop down of the autocomplete results. It works fine if I use the mouse to click the result i want but wont work if i use the enter key.

The first function gets the autocomplete results and the second submits the result to get the data from that particular id.

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function () {



$("#equipment").autocomplete({
    source: "search.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
     $('#eq_id').val(ui.item.id);
    }
  });



$(document).off("keypress", "#equipment");
$(document).on("keypress", "#equipment", function(event) {
//if (!e) e = window.event;   
if (event.keyCode == '13'){
$('#loading').show();
var eq_id = $("#eq_id").val();
var dataString = 'eq_id=' + eq_id;
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "updateForm.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function(html){
    $("#formAddEquip").hide();
    $("#showuserresult").show();
    $("#showuserresult").html(html);
    $("#equipment").val("");
    $('#loading').hide();
  }
});
 return false;
}
});
});
```

And here is the form

```
<form action="" method="post" id="#somesearch">
<label for="equipment" id="eq_id_label">Search Equipment</label>
<input type="text" id="equipment" name="equipment" />
<input type="hidden" id="eq_id" name="eq_id" />
</form>
```

Comment: Do not wrap $(function() in $(document).ready(function () {

Comment: Thanks for the info.. I have updated my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with these improvements

```
$(function() { // only one "load"

  $("#equipment").autocomplete({
    source: "search.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      $('#eq_id').val(ui.item.id);
    }
  });

  $("#somesearch ").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
  });

  $(document).on("keypress", "#equipment", function(event) {
    //if (!e) e = window.event;   
    if (event.keyCode == '13') {
      $('#loading').show();
      var eq_id = $("#eq_id").val();
      var dataString = 'eq_id=' + eq_id;
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "updateForm.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(html) {
          $("#formAddEquip").hide();
          $("#showuserresult").show();
          $("#showuserresult").html(html);
          $("#equipment").val("");
          $('#loading').hide();
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This forces the user to hit enter twice. once to get the result in the field and once to submit the form. Then the submit refreshes the page.

Comment: Unless there are errors in your code, my preventDefault stops the submission as I assumed you would, otherwise the form is submitted instead of the ajax running. If you want to submit, then no need for ajax

Comment: I copied the code directly from your post to test. It starts to load the ajax but then refreshes the page.

Comment: Then you have error in the console. I can obviously not test my code

Comment: Ok.. you are right there was an error in the id of the form. i have left it in the code above to show what was wrong. when i start typing a keyword and they show below the input field, then arrow down and hit enter, the data populates the equipment field but i have to hit enter for the data from that id/keyword to show.

Comment: That is because the first enter is not the enter you test. You need to get at the onselect instead or as well as document.on keypress